Swift - Apple SignIn - User Data Nil
I have implemented Apple Sign In and it was worrking fine as expected but after some days I tested it again but user data is coming nil. Apple signin successfully authanticate the user but when we fall into the delegate method then user name or email is coming nil.
I am using following code
import Foundation
import AuthenticationServices

class LoginWithApple: NSObject {
    func loginRequest() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
}

extension LoginWithApple: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as?  ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
            let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
            let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName
            let email = appleIDCredential.email
            defaults.appleLoginEmail = appleIDCredential.email ?? ""
            defaults.appleIdentifier = userIdentifier

            print("User id is \(userIdentifier) \n Full Name is \(String(describing: fullName)) \n Email id is \(String(describing: email))")
        
        }
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle error.
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


I have also try settings -> profile -> password and security -> apps using your apple id but still getting nil values.

Are you authenticating with an Apple ID that has previously authenticated with your app?  Name and email are only provided the first time that the user completes the Sign in with Apple process.
